# Confused on how this partial integration works

Tags: integration, operator-theory

I am examining the following problem showing the properties of Hermitian operators:

[image]

I can't wrap my head around what was integrated and what was differentiated in the integral. In the first term, one term should be integrated, which appears to be the phi function to which the operator is applied to, but then in the second integral, it appears to look no different from the original integral. What step am I missing here?

Comment: Between line two and line three, the derivative of $\varphi$ was integrated while $\psi$ was differentiated. Between line one and line two, all they did was apply the complex conjugate; no integration by parts was done at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1D momentum operator is a mapping:
$$\hat p:\psi\mapsto \hat p \psi  \\ \hat p\psi=-i\hbar ~\partial_x\psi\tag{1}$$
We also define the inner product:
$$\langle\psi_1\mid\psi_2\rangle=\int_{\Bbb R}{\psi_1}^*(x)\psi_2(x)~\mathrm dx\tag{2}$$

We call a general operator $\hat A$ *Hermitian* if it satisfies
$$\langle \hat{A}\psi_1\mid \psi_2\rangle=\langle\psi_1\mid\hat{A}\psi_2\rangle\tag{3}$$

We can show that $\hat{p}$ is Hermitian. First use the definition of the inner product $(2)$
$$\langle\hat p\psi_1\mid \psi_2\rangle=\int_{\Bbb R}(\hat p\psi_1)^*(x)\psi_2(x)\mathrm dx$$
Now apply the definition of the momentum operator $(1)$:
$$\int_{\Bbb R}(\color{blue}{\hat p\psi_1})^*(x)~\psi_2(x)\mathrm dx=\int_{\Bbb R}(\color{blue}{-i\hbar \partial_x\psi_1})^*(x)~\psi_2(x)\mathrm dx$$
Now use the fact that complex conjugation commutes with multiplication, i.e, $(ab)^*=a^*b^*$, and of course the fact that multiplication commutes with integration:
$$\int_{\Bbb R}(-i\hbar \partial_x\psi_1)^*(x)~\psi_2(x)\mathrm dx=\int_{\Bbb R}(-i\hbar)^* (\partial_x\psi_1)^*(x)~\psi_2(x)\mathrm dx=i\hbar\int_{\Bbb R} (\partial_x\psi_1)^*(x)~\psi_2(x)\mathrm dx$$
Now use the property that complex conjugation commutes with differentiation,
i.e $(\partial_x\phi)^*=\partial_x(\phi^*)$, so
$$i\hbar\int_{\Bbb R} (\partial_x\psi_1)^*(x)~\psi_2(x)\mathrm dx=i\hbar\int_{\Bbb R} (\partial_x{\psi_1}^*)(x)~\psi_2(x)\mathrm dx$$
At this point you can apply the integration by parts, taking $\mathrm dx~\partial_x({\psi_1}^*)=\mathrm dv$ and $u=\psi_2$.
$$i\hbar\int_{\Bbb R} (\partial_x{\psi_1}^*)(x)~\psi_2(x)\mathrm dx=\underbrace{i\hbar\big({\psi_1}^*(x)\psi_2(x)\big)\big|^{x\to\infty}_{x\to-\infty}}_{=0}-i\hbar\int_\Bbb R {\psi_1}^*(x)~(\partial_x\psi_2)(x)\mathrm dx \\ =\int_{\Bbb R}{\psi_1}^*(x)~(-i\hbar \partial_x\psi_2)(x)\mathrm dx \\ =\int_{\Bbb R}{\psi_1}^*(x)~(\hat p \psi_2)(x)\mathrm dx \\ =\langle \psi_1\mid\hat p\psi_2\rangle$$
Hence
$$\langle \hat p\psi_1\mid\psi_2\rangle=\langle\psi_1\mid\hat p\psi_2\rangle \\ \implies \hat p~\text{is Hermitian.}$$

Comment: thank you so much for the clear answer this is exactly what I was looking for!